# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith' when stripping first and last quote from the string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, strip

I am trying to get rid of single quotes around nested dictionaries in pandas data frame (the first element and last element of an object). I am looping through each row in column metadata.

Example of the nested dictionary that is hidden inside of the quotes is below:

`'{"dek": "<p>Don\'t forget to buy a card</p>", "links": {"edit": {"dev": "//patty-menshealth.feature.hearstapps.net/en/content/edit/76517422-96ad-4b5c-a24a-c080c58bce0c", "prod": "//patty-menshealth.prod.com/en/content/edit/76517422-96ad-4b5c-a24a-c080c58bce0c"}}}'`

I tried the following:

```
def string_format(df):
    for text in df.iteritems():
        if text.startswith("'") and text.endswith("'"):
            text = text[1:-1]
            return text

string_format(df["metadata"])
```

Returns AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Comment: You can use `ast.literal_eval` to turn it into `dict`.

Comment: Sure that’s not JSON you’re supposed to parse…?!

Comment: @Ch3steR Currently the type of that column is Series. Should I be converting it into dict?

Comment: Firstly, which code produces that error? Provide a [mcve] extracted from that code, please. Secondly, where do you see "single quotes around nested dictionaries"? Please provide the code for that as well!

Comment: @deceze You were right. json.load(data) worked just fine, it got rid of the single quotes. I am currently trying to apply this to each row in my dataset. Unsuccessful... Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You're using [pandas.Series.iteritems](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iteritems.html) which in fact iterate over (index, value) tuples. So to make your code work, you should try changing your loop like this:

```py
for label, text in df.iteritems():
    # process text
```

But i suggest you checking out pandas documentation on [working with text](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html). For example, you can index your Series directly [via `.str` accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#indexing-with-str).

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I have changed the code but it returns `None` results

Comment: If you're using the same code from your example, that probably would mean your data actually does not start and end with a quote.